Is there a quicker way for Excel VBA to Hide Rows based on a cell value?
I have a some pivot tables in a sheet, with lots of blank rows to separate them so that if one suddenly gets a lot of values it won't overwrite the pivot table underneath.  But to avoid the user having to scroll down quite far to see the other pivot table, I have a formula in column A which checks if anything is populated on each row and have then written some VBA to hide the rows that the formula has identified is empty.
The problem I'm facing is that it is taking 16 seconds just to hide the rows, and it's not even a big range.  Is there a better way I could do this?
For Each cell In Range("A1:A200")
    If cell.Value = "HIDDEN ROW" Then cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cell

The VBA runs in the Worksheet_Change and I ran debug to identify this time lag, and it's results show:



Timestamp
Step




05/06/2024 13:22:27
Start


05/06/2024 13:22:27
Pivot Value check completed


05/06/2024 13:22:27
Checks if the range changed is the Pivot Table filters


05/06/2024 13:22:27
Unhides all cells


05/06/2024 13:22:27
Clears filters


05/06/2024 13:22:27
Sets filters


05/06/2024 13:22:33
Reformatting colours in pivots


05/06/2024 13:22:33
Hiding Rows


05/06/2024 13:22:49
Finish




Filter on the value you want hidden? This may be of use

Try the next adapted solution. Hiding a row at a time it is much time consuming. Using a Union range and hiding all of them at once should be much faster:
Sub HideRows()
  Dim cell As Range, uRng As Range
  For Each cell In Range("A1:A200")
    If cell.Value = "HIDDEN ROW" Then addToRange uRng, cell
 Next cell
 If Not uRng Is Nothing Then uRng.EntireRow.hiden = True
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub


I changed your solution here to append a dummy column at the end to: 1. set constants 2. hide the rows and then 3. delete the dummy column, your solution works wonders for batch row/columns operations

This is perfect, nice and compact and speeds up the process massively.  I was hoping not to have to create a seperate module outside of the Worksheet_Change sub - is it possible to have this all written in the same sub?

Yes, but that solution is a little more complicated, for the case or more then one criteria.  In terms of speed, the above solution is simpler and a littke faster for small ranges as you said...

@seaside_escape No need to create any separate module! You should only replace the code you show in your question with the above one. Of course, copying the function in the same sheet code module. If something stil not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications, specifically describing the problem you are facing...

Solution:
I have enhanced FaneDuru approach to become a function to Hide/Delete Rows or columns. Time savings are stated there. This is the fastest solution that I have tried, I have stressed it to test with around 150k rows analysis hidding many among them and does not sweat.
Demo:

Code:
Sub Exec_AnalyzeRowsToHide()
Dim ArrRowsToHide() As String
Dim CounterRow As Long
    ReDim ArrRowsToHide(1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1 To 1)
    For CounterRow = 1 To 200
    If Cells(CounterRow, 1).Value = "HIDDEN ROW" Then ArrRowsToHide(CounterRow, 1) = "Hide"
    Next CounterRow
    Call Exec_DeleteHideRowsOrColumns(ActiveSheet.Name, ArrRowsToHide, True, "Hide")
End Sub
Sub Exec_DeleteHideRowsOrColumns(TxtSheet As String, ArrTxtPlaceholderValues() As String, IsRowsToDo As Boolean, TxtCase As String)
'array parsed need to be like ArrNumRowsColsToDel(CounterArr, 1)
'Example usage for rows
'at least 6 rows used
'Dim arrnum() As String
'    ReDim arrnum(1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1 To 1)
'    arrnum(2, 1) = "Del": arrnum(4, 1) = "Del": arrnum(6, 1) = "Del"
'    Call Exec_DeleteHideRowsOrColumns(ActiveSheet.Name, arrnum, True,"Del")
'Example usage for columns
'at least 6 columns used
'Dim arrnum() As String
'    ReDim arrnum(1 To Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column, 1 To 1)
'    arrnum(2, 1) = "Del": arrnum(4, 1) = "Del": arrnum(6, 1) = "Del"
'    Call Exec_DeleteHideRowsOrColumns(ActiveSheet.Name, arrnum, False,"Del")
Dim NumLastRowOrColumn As Long
Dim CounterArr As Variant
Dim ArrDummy() As String
Dim NumRowsOrColsAdded As Long
Dim RangeDataSheet As Range
    With Sheets(TxtSheet) ' 1. With Sheets(TxtSheet)
    If IsRowsToDo = True Then ' 1. If IsRowsToDo = True
    NumLastRowOrColumn = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column + 1
    With .Cells(1, NumLastRowOrColumn).Resize(.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1) ' 2. With .Cells(1, NumLastRowOrColumn).Resize(.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    .Value = ArrTxtPlaceholderValues
    Select Case TxtCase
    Case "Del"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    Case "Hide"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Hidden = True: .Parent.Columns(NumLastRowOrColumn).Delete
    End Select
    End With ' 2. With .Cells(1, NumLastRowOrColumn).Resize(.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row, 1)
    .UsedRange
    Else ' 1. If IsRowsToDo = True
    NumLastRowOrColumn = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
    With .Cells(NumLastRowOrColumn, 1).Resize(1, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column) ' 2. With .Cells(NumLastRowOrColumn, 1).Resize(1, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)
    .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ArrTxtPlaceholderValues): DoEvents
    Select Case TxtCase
    Case "Del"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireColumn.Delete
    Case "Hide"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireColumn.Hidden = True: .Parent.Rows(NumLastRowOrColumn).Delete
    End Select
    End With ' 2. With .Cells(NumLastRowOrColumn, 1).Resize(1, .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column)
    .UsedRange
    End If ' 1. If IsRowsToDo = True
    End With ' 1. With Sheets(TxtSheet)
End Sub

